# Novel about scientists who time-travel to Palestine. Their sponsor tries to kill them with robots

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This book is about a group of scientists who go back in time to Palestine on behalf of an (evil) corporation. They meet Jesus and become his apostles. The corporation sends robot-like bugs (with poison) to kill them.

I recall that some kind of talisman or key was involved(?) but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Comment: Time-traveling robots you say?